# How to protect FileTable files from changing or removing by windows users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, filestream, filetable

I've recently migrated my blob tables into FileTables, the problem that I'm facing is people can easily change or remove Files from the disk.

For example I removed a file from the disk and this is what Sql Server tells me when I select a couple of rows from FileTable, sql server showed this error:

```
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
```

As I've already said, people can easily change the files on the disk, for example I opened a file by notepad and I changed its content!

How to protect it from outside changing?

Comment: "As I've already said, people can easily change the files on the disk," : permissions. Users should not be able to get to the server or drives directly

Comment: @MitchWheat
Imagine that an administrator or granted user accidentally change or remove the files.

Comment: "Imagine that an administrator or granted user accidentally change or remove the files" . Fire them. Then get your backups. [Users should not be able to see the drives. PERIOD!]

Comment: @MitchWheat
FileTable performance is great but it is really insecure compare to an ordinary table with varbinary(n)  field.

Comment: Like Mitch has already said, users should not have access to the drives where your files are. If an Administrator accidently deletes a file, ask the administrator to restore the file from backup, if he does it again fire him and get a more reliable Administrator. As far the question of "Granted Users" deleting files, There should be NO Granted Users at all.